# Vertical-align não alinha <li>'s

Tags: css

Gente, estou com um problema no uso do vertical align. As minhas `<li>` do menu inicial tem 80px de altura e configurei para ficarem alinhadas ao meio. Só que não funciona, ué.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhbogwx7/

Answer (score 1):

Altere o display da `.headercontainer li` para **table-cell**.

```
.headercontainer li{
    display:table-cell;
    height:inherit;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Exemplo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rhbogwx7/3/

Comment: Por que? Explicações?

Comment: Isso faz o elemento se comportar como se fosse uma célula de tabela, possibilitando os alinhamentos.

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão:

```
.headercontainer li {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
```

O `transform: translateY(-50%);` é para corrigir a posição, senão ficaria 50% + altura do elemento.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qz1oc8xs/

Comment: Usar CSS3 pra um problema simples não seria gambiarra?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto CSS3 é o futuro. A resposta vai ser cada vez mais válida com o tempo :P E para além disso já há outras sugestões :)

Comment: Isso lá é verdade

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona o line-height: 80px no elemento li. Deixo aqui o fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rhbogwx7/1/

Comment: Dessa forma ele não está usando o vertical-align;